# TortoiseSVN: using ftp location as working copy

Tags: svn, version-control, ftp, tortoisesvn

I need to setup a working copy on the remote FTP server (using TortoiseSVN client).

Direct checkout does not seem to support ftp://... location as a destination folder, mapping a remote folder to a drive letter allows to perform check out but files are not actually being copied to the destination folder specified.

Is this even possible? How? (so far I've found posts that suggest it is and it is not...)

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? IOW, you're attempting to solve a problem, but have already decided on a solution that may be ill-advised. Describe the problem and see what people recommend here. In addition to the startup problems you're having, SQLite (used heavily by the current working copy library) may not react well to this sort of continued use.

Comment: This is the working environment I'm required to build: same folder should be under version control and accessible from outside at the same time (via FTP). Appreciate if you could explain why this is [not] a good idea (SQLite as mentioned already, any other points?)

Comment: Do you have a requirement to connect back to the repository from the FTP server? Time, bandwidth & space are all used in excess with this method. FTP's inherent lack of security. Permissions issues on the server end. Dependency upon a user manually updating this mapped drive (what happens if you're out of the office?). Why not leverage a CI system or even a post-commit hook to push your changes to the server after a commit via rsync or similar, using a more secure connection?

Comment: good point, thanks. will go with local working copy synced to the FTP upon commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses an excess of bandwidth, server space & time to transfer multiple copies of the data via FTP. FTP itself is inherently insecure, so if this is public-facing, you expose yourself to security risks. There may also be permissions issues on the server, and SQLite (used extensively by the working copy library) may not work well in this mode.

Additionally, you're dependent upon a user doing this manually, with a mapped drive on their PC. If that user isn't around when an update is required, what happens?

If there is no requirement to maintain a connection from the FTP server to the repository, it would be preferable to use a CI system or even a simple post-commit hook script to update the contents of the FTP server after a commit is made. If you use rsync, only the bits that have changed will have to be transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem completely, but it sounds like you want to push all files uploaded to the FTP server into SVN?  If so, and if you are running Linux/Unix on the server, then look at [FSVS](http://fsvs.tigris.org/).

You can then set things up with a script to automatically push the FTP folder to the SVN server with a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Only executes FSVS if FSVS reports outstanding changes

FSVS_CONF=~/.fsvs-conf
FSVS_WAA=~/.fsvs-waa
export FSVS_CONF FSVS_WAA

cd /var/ftp

FCOUNT=`/usr/local/bin/fsvs | grep -v 'dir.*\.$' | wc -l`

if [ $FCOUNT -gt 0 ] ; then
    /usr/local/bin/fsvs ci -m "Automatic FSVS snapshot"
else
    echo "Nothing changed"
fi
```